# Blackjack Charlie Probabilities

Tags: r, blackjack

I am trying to figure out how to find the probabilities of a player getting a 5 card charlie (i.e draws 5 cards without busting) in Blackjack with 4 or 7 decks of cards.....

I have tried the following formula and it just does not work....it works for a 1 deck but not 4 decks.... i.e. if I put in the nos 4 and 16 instead of 16 & 64 it works but I cannot get it to work for 4 or 7 decks of cards#

```
deck <- c(rep(1:9, 16), rep(10, 64))
acceptable <- function(x) {sum(x) <= 21}
sum(combn(deck, 5, acceptable))
```

Anybody any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: Are you getting an error message or an incorrect output?

Comment: thanks Aziz. Yes as follows:

Comment: deck <- c(rep(1:9, 16), rep(10, 64))
> acceptable <- function(x) {sum(x) <= 21}
> sum(combn(deck, 5, acceptable))
Error in matrix(r, nrow = len.r, ncol = count) : 
  invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)
In addition: Warning message:
In combn(deck, 5, acceptable) : NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
>